# @Valid is validating in rest api in spring boot

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to validate a requestbody of rest api using spring annotation.The project is created using Spring Boot.
I have annotated the class with @NotNull and @Valid with @RequestBody. After trying all my ways, it's not validating.
Can anyone please help me on this?

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

@Autowired
private ValidateErrors validateErrors;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> resisterEmployee( @Valid @RequestBody EmployeesVO employees , BindingResult errors) throws EmployeeValidationException  {
    try {           
            validateErrors.checkError(errors);
            //return new ResponseEntity<Void>(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); 
    }
    catch(EmployeeValidationException validationException) {
        throw new EmployeeValidationException("2001", "Invalid Input");
    }
    }
public class EmployeesVO {

@NotNull
@JsonProperty("team_members")
List<TeamMember> employeeList ;
//getters & setters
 }

public class TeamMember extends Employees{
@NotNull
private Integer team_member_id;
//getters and setters
}
```

While debugging I could see that the hasErrors() returs false(No errors).
Please note that employee class also has 2 fields which are annotated as @NotNull

Comment: show us your request body.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `org.springframework.validation.Errors` instead of using `BindingResult`.
Then, if any errors is present, you can return a `ResponseEntity.badRequest()` with error body.